# How to create a click listener forEach() class

Tags: javascript

Forgive me in advance since I am only a OOPHP developer, however, I am trying to integrate a client side live chat with friends*.

I have made a demo version of real data, here is my current code:

```js
var chat = {
 open: function(id) {
   console.log(id);
  }
};

var chatBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('chat-single');

// WORKS
chatBtns[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
 chat.open(this.getAttribute('id'));
});

/* DOESNT WORK
chatBtns.forEach(function(btn){
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
     chat.open(this.getAttribute('id'));
    });
});
*/
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  color: purple;
}
.chat-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}
.chat-single {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class='chat-wrapper'>
  <p class='online-friends'>
  Online Friends: (<span class='chat-online'>2</span>)
  </p>
  <div class='chat-friends'>
    <a class='chat-single' title='chat with Some Name' href='#' id='unique-id-here'>Some Name</a>
    <a class='chat-single' title='chat with Some Other Name' href='#' id='unique-id-here'>Some Other Name</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The unique chat identity for that friend* is held inside an attribute `id`. Each button (`chat-single`) when clicked will take the `id` attribute and send it to the `chat.open()` method.

I have debugged this code and seen that `chatBtns` is a data-type array, therefore, I looked at the [`forEach()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). The issue here is that when I state the `0` index point, it works. When I use the `forEach()` it gives me an error that the method does not exist.

Any help here would be perfect, could I also get an explanation to how it works  so I can understand what I was missing.

Please note I do not want to use any libraries to achieve this (ie: jQuery).

Comment: You could use a simple for loop or convert it to an array via something like `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('chat-single')).forEach`

Comment: This worked, I don't understand why? I `console.log(chatBtns);` and it is already an Array.. Could you add an answer explaining? Thanks so much @E.Sundin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple array-like objects in JavaScript which does not behave exactly like the JavaScript [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

What you have returned from your selection is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

```
document.getElementsByClassName('chat-single') instanceof HTMLCollection // true
document.getElementsByClassName('chat-single') instanceof Array // false
```

I suggested using the following code to get an array of the array-like object:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('‌​chat-single'))
```

`Array.prototype.slice` is a function to return a copy of the entire, or some parts, of the array upon which it is called.

`call` calls the slice function with the selection as `this` which returns the array-like object as an array.

So now you actually have an array of your previous data so calling `.forEach` is possible.

Comment: that is so clear, I really appreciate the `instanceof` in this answer. That will come in helpful later! Thank-you again

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal for loop to iterate over the HTMLCollections. Try this

```js
var chat = {
  open: function(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }
};

var chatBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('chat-single');


// WORKS
/*chatBtns[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
 chat.open(this.getAttribute('id'));
});*/

/* DOESNT WORK ==> Now it works :)*/
for (var i = 0; i < chatBtns.length; i++) {
  chatBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    chat.open(this.getAttribute('id'));
  });
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  color: purple;
}
.chat-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}
.chat-single {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class='chat-wrapper'>
  <p class='online-friends'>
    Online Friends: (<span class='chat-online'>2</span>)
  </p>
  <div class='chat-friends'>
    <a class='chat-single' title='chat with Some Name' href='#' id='unique-id-here'>Some Name</a>
    <a class='chat-single' title='chat with Some Other Name' href='#' id='unique-id-here'>Some Other Name</a>
  </div>
</div>
```